# BASH grep with multiple parameters + n lines after one of the matches

Tags: bash, grep

I have a bunch of text as a output from command, I need to display only specific matching lines plus some additional lines after match "message" (message text is obviously longer than 1 line)

what I tried was:

```
grep -e 'Subject:' -e 'Date:' -A50 -e 'Message:'
```

but it included 50 lines after EACH match, and I need to pass that only to single parameter. How would I do that?

code with output command:

```
(<...> | telnet <mailserver> 110 | grep -e 'Subject:' -e 'Date:' -A50 -e 'Message:'
```

Part of the telnet output:

```
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 16 
Message-ID: <00fb01ceae25$ 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_00FC_01CEAE3E.DE32CE40"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0
Thread-Index: Ac6uJWYdA3lUzs1cT8....
Content-Language: lt
X-Mailman-Approved-At: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 16:0 ....
Subject: ...
X-BeenThere: ...
Precedence: list
```

Comment: Can you paste sample input and expected output as its not clear what exactly you need.

Comment: What input are you going to supply to command grep -e 'Subject:' -e 'Date:' -A50 -e 'Message:'? And what are the expected output. Hope its clear?

Comment: the input is email message outputted from telnet command. It's very long and includes many unnecessary technical details. In the final output I only need 1 line for Subject and Date + 50 lines for the message text.

Comment: You could morph and create some data for our understanding. We dont need whole loads of data. Reason is we need to understand what exactly the issue is. Without these am afraid we would be able to help you.

Comment: I'am not sure you are following me. The issue is simple, it now outputs 50 additional lines after EACH match. Now I get 1 line for subject + 50 following lines (which include unneeded technical stuff like MIME-Version and MessageID code), 1 for Date + 50, etc... I'am looking for a way to specify for grep command to include additional lines after only one of my specified parameters, not all of them.

Comment: egrep 'Subject:|Date:|Message:' is this what you are after? I still dont get it :(

Comment: Okay I included the part of the output in the OP. As you can see, there is a bunch of technical stuff which I don't need. I need to output 1 line which contains "Subject:", one for "Date:" and 1 line which contains "Message:" + 50 lines following after that where the actual message would be.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
... | telnet ... > <file>
grep -e 'Subject:' -e 'Date:' <file> && grep -A50 -e 'Message:' <file>
```

Will need to dump the output to a file first.

This can be done with `awk` as well, without the need for dumping output to a file.

```
... | telnet ... | awk '/Date:/ {print}; /Subject:/ {print}; /Message:/ {c=50} c && c--'
```

Answer (score 0):

With grep it would be hard to do. Better use `awk` for this

```
awk '/Subject:|Date:/;/Message:/ {while(l<=50){print $0;l++;getline}}'
```

Here the `awk` prints 50 lines below the `Message:` pattern and only one line is printed for all other patterns.

Comment: That should do it, but one question. What if the match has a '/' in it? For example let's say 'Message/text' is our match, how to make it work without breaking the syntax?

Comment: In AWK you have to escape '/' with '\' and so the regex would be like `/Message\/text/`